# How to Smooth the drawing Stroke?

Tags: xcode, paint

I am creating drawing.. i can undo, and put colors on it. but when i draw using my fingers the stroke is not that smooth and has edge lines,,

here my codes. on which I can Paint on a view, Undo, change color, and the opacity.

stroke.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface stroke : UIView{
    NSMutableArray *strokeArray;
    UIColor *strokeColor;
    int strokeSize;
    float strokeAlpha;
    int strokeAlpha2;
    IBOutlet UISlider *slides;
    float red;
    float green;
    float blue;
    CGPoint mid1;
    CGPoint mid2; 
    CGPoint endingPoint,previousPoint1,previousPoint2;
    CGPoint currentTouch;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *strokeColor;
@property (nonatomic) int strokeSize;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *strokeArray;
- (IBAction)changeAlphaValue;
-(void)loadSLider;
-(void)blueColor;
-(void)darkvioletColor;
-(void)violetColor;
-(void)pinkColor;
-(void)darkbrownColor;
-(void)redColor;
-(void)magentaRedColor;
-(void)lightBrownColor;
-(void)lightOrangeColor;
-(void)OrangeColor;
-(void)YellowColor;
-(void)greenColor;
-(void)lightYellowColor;
-(void)darkGreenColor;
-(void)TurquioseColor;
-(void)PaleTurquioseColor;
-(void)skyBlueColor;
-(void)whiteColor;
-(void)DirtyWhiteColor;
-(void)SilverColor;
-(void)LightGrayColor;
-(void)GrayColor;
-(void)LightBlackColor;
-(void)BlackColor;
@end
```

stroke.m

```
#import "stroke.h"

@implementation stroke
@synthesize strokeColor;
@synthesize strokeSize;
@synthesize strokeArray;


- (void) awakeFromNib{
    self.strokeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:232 alpha:1];
    self.strokeSize = 3;
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    NSMutableArray *stroke;
    for (stroke in strokeArray) {
        CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, [[stroke objectAtIndex:1] intValue]);
        CGFloat *color = CGColorGetComponents([[stroke objectAtIndex:2] CGColor]);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, color[0], color[1], color[2], color[3]);    
        CGContextBeginPath(contextRef);
        CGPoint points[[stroke count]];
        for (NSUInteger i = 3; i < [stroke count]; i++) {
            points[i-3] = [[stroke objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
        }
        CGContextAddLines(contextRef, points, [stroke count]-3);
        CGContextStrokePath(contextRef);
    }

}
-(void)loadSLider{

}
- (IBAction)changeAlphaValue{
    strokeAlpha2 =((int)slides.value);
}
-(void)blueColor{
    red = 0/255.0;
    green = 0/255.0;
    blue = 255/255.0;
}
-(void)darkvioletColor{
    red = 75/255.0;
    green = 0/255.0;
    blue = 130/255.0;
}
-(void)violetColor{
    red = 128/255.0;
    green = 0/255.0;
    blue = 128/255.0;
}
-(void)pinkColor{
    red = 255/255.0;
    green = 0/255.0;
    blue = 255/255.0;
}
-(void)darkbrownColor{
    red = 0.200;
    green = 0.0;
    blue = 0.0;
}
-(void)redColor{
    red = 255/255.0;
    green = 0/255.0;
    blue = 0/255.0;
}
-(void)magentaRedColor{
    red = 0.350;
    green = 0.0;
    blue = 0.0;
}
-(void)lightBrownColor{
    red = 0.480;
    green = 0.0;
    blue = 0.0;
}
-(void)lightOrangeColor{
    red = 0.600;
    green = 0.200;
    blue = 0.0;
}
-(void)OrangeColor{
    red = 1.0;
    green = 0.300;
    blue = 0.0;
}
-(void)YellowColor{
    red = 0.950;
    green = 0.450;
    blue = 0.0;
}
-(void)greenColor{
    red = 0.0;
    green = 1.0;
    blue = 0.0;
}
-(void)lightYellowColor{
    red = 1.0;
    green = 1.0;
    blue = 0.0;

}
-(void)darkGreenColor{
    red = 0.0;
    green = 0.500;
    blue = 0.0;
}
-(void)TurquioseColor{
    red = 0.0;
    green = 0.700;
    blue = 0.200;
}
-(void)PaleTurquioseColor{
    red = 0.0;
    green = 0.700;
    blue = 0.600;
}
-(void)skyBlueColor{
    red = 0.0;
    green = 0.400;
    blue = 0.800;
}
-(void)whiteColor{
    red = 1.0;
    green = 1.0;
    blue = 1.0;
}
-(void)DirtyWhiteColor{
    red = 0.800;
    green = 0.800;
    blue = 0.800;
}
-(void)SilverColor{
    red = 0.600;
    green = 0.600;
    blue = 0.600;
}
-(void)LightGrayColor{
    red = 0.500;
    green = 0.500;
    blue = 0.500;
}
-(void)GrayColor{
    red = 0.300;
    green = 0.300;
    blue = 0.300;
}
-(void)LightBlackColor{
    red = 0.150;
    green = 0.150;
    blue = 0.150;
}
-(void)BlackColor{
    red = 0.0;
    green = 0.0;
    blue = 0.0;
}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch;

    NSEnumerator *counter = [touches objectEnumerator];
    while ((touch = (UITouch *)[counter nextObject])) {
        switch (strokeAlpha2) {
            case 1:
                strokeAlpha = .1;
                break;
            case 2:
                strokeAlpha = .2;
                break;
            case 3:
                strokeAlpha = .3;
                break;
            case 4:
                strokeAlpha = .4;
                break;
            case 5:
                strokeAlpha = .5;
                break;
            case 6:
                strokeAlpha = .6;
                break;
            case 7:
                strokeAlpha = .7;
                break;
            case 8:
                strokeAlpha = .8;
                break;
            case 9:
                strokeAlpha = .9;
                break;
            case 10:
                strokeAlpha = 1;
                break;
            default:
                strokeAlpha = 1;
                break;
        }

        self.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:strokeAlpha];
        NSValue *touchPos = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[touch locationInView:self]];
        UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:strokeColor.CGColor];
        NSNumber *size = [NSNumber numberWithInt:strokeSize]; 
        NSMutableArray *stroke = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: touch, size, color, touchPos, nil];
        [strokeArray addObject:stroke];
    }
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch;

    NSEnumerator *counter = [touches objectEnumerator];

    while ((touch = (UITouch *)[counter nextObject])) {
        NSMutableArray *stroke;
        for (stroke in strokeArray) {
            if ([stroke objectAtIndex:0] == touch) {
                [stroke addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[touch locationInView:self]]];
            }
            [self setNeedsDisplay];
        }
    }
}



@end
```

Comment: I have one other way to do it. With less code and soother lines. If you like to experiment with it you can get lost more smoother lines with it Just try [this](https://github.com/AalokParikh/iOS-drawing) out

Comment: @Wolvorin thanks,, I already tried it,, and It have problem with the colorchanging of the code.. can't change the color of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `CGContextAddLines()` you should make a bezier path using `CGContextAddCurveToPoint()`. You'll need to construct it out of 4 points, so you'll probably need to use the previous and next 2 points, or something along those lines.

Comment: i try it already, but it doesn't read the CGContextAddCurveToPoint() code.